# Arithmetic Series Word problem

Tags: sequences-and-series, word-problem

Taking a calculus class and trying to solve a series and sequence word problem but I am struggling on the easiest problem. Please someone talk me thru a baby step on this question please?

1) Xin has been given a 14 day training schedule by her coach. Xin will fun for A minutes on day 1, where A is a constant. 
She will then increase her running time by (d+1) minutes each day, where d is a constant.
a) Show that on day 14, Xin will run for

````
```(A + 13d +13) minutes```
````

At this point I think I understand that I can write formula as 
    `a+(n-1)d` where `a = A` and `d=(d+1)` and `n=14`

2) Yi has also been given a 14 day training schedule by her coach.
Yi will run for (A-13) minutes on day 1.
She will then increase her running time by `(2d-1)` minutes each day.
Given that Yi and Xin will run for the same length of time on day 14,

b) find the value of d.

My understanding is that the formula be written as

`a = (A-13)`, `n = 14`, `d=(2d-1)`

At this point I don't know how to find the answer of question b. Something is telling me its a problem that I can use system of linear equation to find value of d. But I am not certain. Please can someone help me?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you surround math expressions by `$` signs instead of back ticks, they'll get formatted properly.

Comment: Begin by writing down how far Yi runs on day $14$; you did this correctly for Xin, so just use the same idea for Yi. You are making one consistent mistake, though: you’re using $d$ both for the unknown constant in the problem and as a generic symbol for the common difference of the arithmetic sequence. It makes no sense to write $d=d+1$; you need to use a different generic symbol, perhaps $D$ for the common difference. Then you can say that $D=d+1$ for Xin and that $D=2k-1$ for Yi. No need for a system of equations: just set $A+13d+13$ equal to the figure that you get for Yi and solve for $d$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so for Yi will be
   $(A + 26d +26)$ 
which makes:
  $(A + 13d +13)$  = $(A + 26d +26)$ 
is this correct?

so can you suggest what the next step is? I suppose I need to find A first to be able to solve d?

Comment: @PeddiePooh: Not quite: $13(2d-1)=26d-13$, not $26d+26$. Fix that, and you’ll have $$A+13d+13=A+26d-13\;,$$ and you can solve this for $d$ without knowing $A$: just subtract $A$ from both sides of the equation.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so d=2 is that correct?

Comment: @PeddiePooh: I apologize: I forgot that Yi started at $A-13$, not at $A$, so I should have had $$A+13d+13=A-13+26d-13=A+26d-26\;.$$ Your solution $d=2$ is correct for the erroneous equation that I gave you; for the correct equation you’ll get $d=\;$... ?

Comment: Thank you - d = 3 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking to plug numbers into the formula don't use $d$ for both $d$ and $d+1$.

Your formula for an arithmetic sequence seems to be if $a = $ Value of first day. And $d=$ the amount changed each day then $a_n = $ the value on day $n = a+ (n-1)d$.

This is fine.

But as the variable $d$ is given to mean something arbitrarily *different* we have to use a different variable in our formula.  And variables are just notation we could use anything.

I'll just put the formula with a capital $D$ so that $a_n = $ the value on day $n = a + (n-1)D$ where we have $D= d+1$ and $a=A$.

So the formula is $a_{14} = a + (14-1)D= a+13D  = A+13(d+1) = A + 13d + 13.

For 2)

We have $a = (A-13)$ and $D = 2d-1$ and the formula is that on the $14$th day she will run $a + (14-1)D = a+13D = (A-13) +13(2d-1) = A -13 + 26d-13=A+26d - 26$.

So we are told that Xi who ran $A+13d + 13$ on the $14$th day and Yi who ran $A+26d$ on the fourteenth day ran the same ammount on the 14th day.

So $A + 13d + 13 = A + 26d-26$.

Solve for $d$.

Note:  We don't need to know what $A$ is.  If we subtract $A$ from both sides we have

$A+13d + 13 = A + 26d -26$ so

$A+13d + 13-A =A+26d -26 -A$ so

$(A-A) + 13d + 13 = (A-A) + 26d -26$ so

$13d + 13 = 26d - 26$

continue..